# Need a way to determine if getdate() is between a very specific season with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have an interesting dilemma that I need to be able to handle often in a subquery, and of course the least expensive method. Now I've solved the issue but I'm still asking the question because I'm betting there's a better way?

I have a table for seasons that are very specific, and winters jumps to the next year, and that, is my issue.

Example of how I was initially handling it before I realized I made a stupid mistake:

```
SeasonId | Name   | From       | To
-------------------------------------------
1        | Winter | 1900-12-01 | 1900-02-28
etc.
```

As stated before I have to query this on a consistent basis and was trying to keep it as simple as possible. Using this all over the place in subqueries and clauses:

```
WHERE datefromparts(1900, month(getdate()), day(getdate())) 
between [From] AND [To]
```

You see the bone-head mistake? Winter's from date is the same year, so of course right now (Winter as of this question) all these queries fail.

So to solve this, I added the following columns:

1. Leap tinyint (I set this to 1 for Winter and 0 for the rest)
2. MonthFrom tinyint
3. DayFrom tinyint
4. MonthTo tinyint
5. DayTo tinyint
6. ComputedFrom (computed column)
7. ComputedTo (computed column)

The `ComputedFrom` formula looks like this:

```
(datefromparts(datepart(year,getdate()),[MonthFrom],[DayFrom]))
```

The `ComputedTo` formula looks like this:

```
(datefromparts(datepart(year,dateadd(year,[Leap],getdate())),[MonthTo],[DayTo]))
```

The concept of this query and why/how it's needed can logically be summed up by this example:

```
SELECT CoatType FROM dbo.Coats 
WHERE getdate() BETWEEN ComputedFrom AND ComputedTo
```

Have I overcomplicated this? I need to set it and forget it, perhaps a minor change for a leap year or something when that time arises.

Comment: And the problem is? Add some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: Do the season start/end dates float from year to year such that you really do need a table with every year and its corresponding season dates? That would be like Daylight Saving Time being shuffled about by various political entities, e.g individual counties in Indiana.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the comparison as:

```
where ([From] <= [To] and datefromparts(1900, month(getdate()), day(getdate())) 
between [From] and [To]
      ) or
      ([From] >= [To] and datefromparts(1900, month(getdate()), day(getdate())) 
not between [From] and [To]
      )
```

Comment: Looking at this, I may run into an issue where I get back more than one season? For example if it's `3/1/2019` I would get back Winter and Spring. This could be user error on my part for not adding more examples in my question.

Comment: @user1447679 . . . That would only happen if you had overlapping seasons.

Comment: Trying to build a fiddle for this but sqlfiddle is having some issues at the moment. Using 3/1/2019 I get back Winter and Spring. I'll update here when I can get some sample data up for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this correctly, it might be enough to have a look at the month:

```
DECLARE @dt DATE = GETDATE();

SELECT CASE MONTH(@dt) WHEN 1 THEN 'Winter'
                       WHEN 2 THEN 'Winter'
                       WHEN 3 THEN 'Spring'                      
                       WHEN 4 THEN 'Spring'                       
                       WHEN 5 THEN 'Spring'
                       WHEN 6 THEN 'Summer'
                       WHEN 7 THEN 'Summer'
                       WHEN 8 THEN 'Summer'
                       WHEN 9 THEN 'Autumn'
                       WHEN 10 THEN 'Autumn'
                       WHEN 11 THEN 'Autumn'
                       WHEN 12 THEN 'Winter' END;
```

Comment: Part of the issue is those dates may change. They are seasonal but not necessarily strict within those dates. It's a situation where the season may be predetermined and change. So winter "specials" may bleed into 3/1 one year.

Comment: @user1447679 You might store your seasons as `StartDay` and `DurationDays`. It should be easy to compute your `To` as `DATEADD(DAY,DurationDays,StartDay)`. This way your *over the year*-issue should be solved...

Comment: @user1447679 Even simpler: You store the `StartDate` only. So you have to check for *greater or equal to `StartDate` and smaller than the next `StartDate`* (look into `LAG()` and `LEAD()`)

Comment: @user1447679 For performance sake you can add a `To` column and compute the values with an `UPDATE` or even with a `TRIGGER` on any `insert` of a new `StartDate`...

Comment: Very interesting ideas here. I need to digest. Thank you